# NumPy array element weirdly changes when selected

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I made a simple linear equation system solver using NumPy arrays. I have two arrays on hand: a 2x2 (A) one and a 2x1 one (B).

By inverting the first one using `Ainv = np.linalg.inv(A)` and then multiplying it with the second one using `Ainv.dot(B)`, I get a third 2x1 array with my desired x and y values, which is returned by the function, called `solveLin()` by the way.

Now if I print out `print(solveLin())` with the variables in place, I do get the array `[[-8.]
[ 5.]]` with the correct values.

However, if I target the values with `print(solveLin()[0][0])` for example, I get `-7.999999999999998` and `4.999999999999999` as my answers.

If I set them to display as integers, they become -7 and 4

Edit: I do understand why floating numbers act this way, but I do not understand why are they displayed one way in the array and then another way when called directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @ForceBru then I do not understand why does it display the values differently in the array.

Comment: that's because NumPy tries to show these imprecise values in a user-friendly way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy is trying to be helpful and print things readable. See [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions) for a long explanation of what it's doing.

Printing in python calls str and str is not expected to print precise things, just informative. repr() is for precise representations.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to, fundamentally, the fact that binary, which is what numpy uses to crunch numbers, is difficult to precisely represent in decimal and vice-versa. Look at how we are used to representing one-third in decimal, 0.33333333.. In python, 0.1 is 0.100000000000000005551115123125..
Here is a link from python docs on the matter : [Decimal fixed point and floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)